# Simplify repeating jQuery code

Tags: jquery, simplify

I've set up a modal overlay and have this code which could be simplified, I just don't know how to do it.

In theory there will be more than 6 code blocks, so ideally this should cope with as many as possible. The ID's (1 to 6) are generated dynamically using PHP.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// Load dialog on click
$('.open-modal-overlay-1').click(function (e) {
    $('#modal-overlay-1').modal();

    return false;
});

$('.open-modal-overlay-2').click(function (e) {
    $('#modal-overlay-2').modal();

    return false;
});

$('.open-modal-overlay-3').click(function (e) {
    $('#modal-overlay-3').modal();

    return false;
});

$('.open-modal-overlay-4').click(function (e) {
    $('#modal-overlay-4').modal();

    return false;
});

$('.open-modal-overlay-5').click(function (e) {
    $('#modal-overlay-5').modal();

    return false;
});

$('.open-modal-overlay-6').click(function (e) {
    $('#modal-overlay-6').modal();

    return false;
});

});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do the elements have other classes in addition to the `open-modal-overlay-X` class?

Comment: you can check the jQuery regex selector features to match the classes

Answer (score 3):

The best implementation depends on what factors we can assume about the rest of your markup.

Can we assume that *all* `open-modal-overlay-*` should have this click listener?
Can we assume that this is the *only* class they have? In that case, we could do something like:

```
$('*[class^=open-modal-overlay-]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('class').slice(-1); // last char of "class" attribute
    $('#modal-overlay-'+id).modal();
});
```

If we can't assume that this is their only class, then we can't use `.attr('class')` like that, nor can we use the "class attribute starts with" selector `class^=`. If they all have another common class, that is unique to them, we could perhaps better access them by `$('.open-modal-overlay')` (if, say, their class attributes are `class="open-modal-overlay open-modal-overlay-2"` etc).

If not, we'd have to use the "class attribute contains" selector, `class*=`, or simply specify the selectors:

```
$('.open-modal-overlay-1, .open-modal-overlay-2, .open-modal-overlay-3, .open-modal-overlay-4, .open-modal-overlay-5, .open-modal-overlay-6').click(function() {
   ...
});
```

And we couldn't derive the `id` variable like that, so we'd have to do something like:

```
var id = $(this).attr('class').replace(/^.*open-modal-overlay-(\d+).*$/, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).each(function (i, e) {
    $('.open-modal-overlay-' + e).click(function () {
        $('#modal-overlay-' + e).modal();
        return false;
    })
});
```